# matplotlib pandas: key error. Can't plot two columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot, keyerror

this seems like a very simple question but I can't figure out why I keep running into this error.
I would like to plot two columns called time and y from a pandas dataframe, but it always generates the following error:

> KeyError: 'time'

which is strange, because If I plot x and y, it runs smoothly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

data=[[1, 1,2 ,5],
        [2, 5,5,6],
        [3, 4,6,6]
        ,[5, 6,5,6],
        [7,9,9,7],
        [8, 7,9,4]
        ,[9, 2,3,8],
        [2, 5,1,9],
        [2,2,10,9]
        ,[3, 8,2,8],
        [6, 5,4,10],
        [6, 8,5 ,10]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time','x','y','target'])
df=df.groupby('time').sum()
plt.plot(df['time'],df['y'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Strange, I got no errors when executing this code

Comment: sorry, I forgot the groupby line

Comment: "df.groupby(['time']).sum()" and don't assign back to df !

Comment: this line works with this dataframe, however, it does not with another one. Any idea why ?